# Database Design phonebook

Tags: database, database-design

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `number` varchar(11) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `confirmCode` int(5) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'if empty, then verified',
  `pic` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `link` int(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=53 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `users`
--

INSERT INTO `users` (`ID`, `number`, `password`, `confirmCode`, `pic`, `name`, `gender`, `link`) VALUES
(50, '5105858953', '81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055', 73485, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(52, '4086672806', 'eeafff918f30a0d33ed9a3f4073d5be6', 89290, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

---

Or should i use one table and have an extra field in users that contains all their contacts and custom names of that contact like such

123-530-2340:Bob;555-402-1323:Billy;555-419-2301:Joe;

What are the benefits of each and which should I use if I want reads to be fast

Comment: Part of your question seems to be missing.  Your better off normalizing your data.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: you'd better learn the Entity Relation model first.